# Where should we ask software testing questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, policy, testing

We've got stack overflow for developers, super user for "computer enthusiasts", server fault for IT pros and network admins and meta for questions on policy of other things.

So what about software testing questions?  It looks like this is the one major profession you've missed.

And that's assuming architects, requirements / technical writers can use stack overflow - is that the case?

Comment: Make an Area51 proposal :)

Comment: Eh? I don't understand.

Comment: You can propose a new site to cover this material here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create, though in my opinion SO is the right forum for Software Test questions

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification - good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing it what way? On the unit testing or the user interface level? Because the former clearly belongs on SO, and questions regarding the latter have very good chances to live on SO in my experience,e ven if they aren't 110% *programming* related as such.

If you have questions in the field, I'd say it's best to simply go ahead and ask them. Nothing worse can happen than that they get closed - no real harm done, and people will have it easier to voice their opinions when they have something to look at.

I personally would love to see such questions on SO proper, and not a SE spin-off. (That's just one man's opinion, though.)

Questions tagged [`Unit-Testing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) and [`testing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=testing&sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Comment: I like that answer because you distinguish different levels of testing. I had in mind more "career" testers, e.g. system / acceptance level but you're right - developers also run component levels tests.  Still - is SO only for programming questions or for questions from programmers?

Comment: @Mark This is prbably a grey area. I'd say try it out. Be sure to post a link to your question(s) here - if it's not *completely* programming unrelated like "how do I clean my eye-tracking system attached to our test PC?", you'll have my reopen vote, and voiced opinion, if you need it.

Comment: @Mark also once there is a couple of questions, people here (and moderators and the management) will have something concrete to look at and judge whether it belongs or not. It's hard for me to imagine a typical testing question beyond the unit testing level.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the vote of support!